# HttpRequests in python not picked up by django

Tags: python, django, http

I am currently trying to create a REST web service for my django site from scratch and I do not want to use external libraries as this is supposed to be a learning experience. One of my applications act as the web application while the other will act as the web service. I have plenty of examples on how to implement the web service and return Http responses but the problem is generating and sending http requests which I don't have an example of. I want my application to send a http request to the other application which receives it and responds.

The web service responds perfectly to browser-generated request. I simply write the resource's address in the address bar and I get the expected response. 
I've tested using python's built-in urllib2's urlopen but it will hang forever, possibly because the socket is occupied. I do realize that I haven't specified a time-out, but my concern is more that the request is never picked up by the server. There is no log of the request ever occurring. The url in code and in browser are identical.

Is there a way in django to simply generate a Httprequest and send it on its way without much fuss?

```
#This is the offending line. 
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/browse/')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just because the development server is single-threaded. It can't both be responding to the original request from the client and the request that's generated internally, so it will hang.

Comment: Okay, so the urlopen call goes into waiting mode after sending the request, preventing the server from ever responding. But how should I do it then? I was hoping of not having to run the applications in separate servers.

Comment: It's only a limitation of the dev server, and wouldn't happen in production.

Comment: I will accept your answer. It's not the one I was looking for but nevertheless a correct answer. I skipped the message passing by simply calling functions while still offering a web service to http requests. To ensure those worked I made use of the django test module.